# Matlab inverse fast fourier tansform for frequency-wavenumber field, do I need make conjugation and flip?

Tags: matlab, fft, waveform

First I describe the physics, it is in a axisymmetric space, one sound source was placed at the original point, one sensor was placed on the axis under the source. Giving the source wave form, I try to get the sensor's waveform. all materiel parameter were known, for instance, sound speed, density.

I write the Matlab script to calculate it, by solving the sound propagation equation I can get 
one function, say, A(w,k), w is frequency and k is wavenumber, this is so called frequency-wavenumber field. My matlab code like this,
discrete w and k, get a A array. first use FFT to k, get space and frequency information
then, FFT to w, get space and time information, that is the waveform at different point.

the fake code

```
for i_w=...
w=...
 for i_k=...
 k=...
 M=A(w,k)
 end 
wave_space_freq=ifft(M)  
end  % here can specify the only point of the sensor
wave_space_freq=ifft(wave_space_freq)
```

My question is do I need to make conjugation and flip when I use IFFT,like ifft(M,0,fliplr(conj(M))) . because I saw some-others use them, but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a strictly real-valued result waveform (not complex with significant imaginary components), then the input to an IFFT has to be conjugate symmetric, such as:
ifft(dc_term,M,0,fliplr(conj(M))).

Comment: If I want to plot the waveform, does it work? by ifft(dc_term,M,0,fliplr(conj(M))) or just use real(M), would you explain to me why I should do this